# Merging methods (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: java, methods, merge, binary-search-tree

I'm working on writing a BST (Binary Search Tree) and there's an example in a book I'm reading that gives this code

```
public int height() {
    return height(root);
}

private int height(BinaryNode<E> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int leftHeight = height(node.left);
        int rightHeight = height(node.right);

        if (leftHeight < rightHeight) {
            return 1 + rightHeight;
        } else {
            return 1 + leftHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

but there's no explanatory information about why there's two separate height methods. 
Therefore I'm asking you guys if it's possible to merge these two methods in to one height method. Is it possible, if not. Why not?

Appreciative for any help possible,
Bob.

Answer (score 1):

It's an example of [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).
There are two methods with the same name, that differs by the number of type of arguments passed.

The first method has no parameter, the second one has one parameter of type `BinaryNode<E>`.
When the first method is called, it calls the second one passing to it the `root` variable (which I assume is of type `BinaryNode<E>`).

The first one is also public, so you can call it from other classes, the second one is private and is callable only from the class where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the methods you provided are part of the tree class, then I don't see how you can merge them. The first is a public method, which expects no argument, and the second is a helper recursive method that checks the height of a given node. The first one uses the second: it invokes the helper method on the root itself. The second method shouldn't be visible from outside, so it's private.

If the height method was implemented on the Node level, then it could be done in a single recursive method with no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `int height()` method is **public**. This is the one that will be called from outside your class. It must decide the height of the tree. It will do this by calling the other one.

See also that the `int height(BinaryNode<E> node)` is **private** because it is used only by the `public int height()` method to determine the height of any subtree.